# Return value of obfuscation function

Tags: c, deobfuscation

I'm trying to find the return value of this function:

```
char __slp_f1tb1t(char x) {


const static unsigned char _[2][2][2][2] = {


{ { { 0x00, 0x10 }, { 0x20, 0x30 } },


{ { 0x40, 0x50 }, { 0x60, 0x70 } } },


{ { { 0x80, 0x90 }, { 0xA0, 0xB0 } }, 


{ { 0xC0, 0xD0 }, { 0xE0, 0xF0 } } }


};

return _[!!(x&0x80)][!!(x&0x40)][!!(x&0x20)][!!(x&0x10)] | (x&15); 

}
```

How am I supposed to proceed? I think I do not understand what the char _[2][2][2][2] means.

Comment: `_` is the identifer of the 4-D arrray.

Comment: All right! However, I do not know how to proceed anyway.

Comment: Look at the first index calculation. `x&0x80` will be non-0 if bit 7 of the argument `x` is set. `!` will reduce that to a boolean `0` or `1`. The other `!` will invert it. So the expression reduces to `0` or `1` which are valid index values in range. Similarly for the other index calculations.

Comment: @LudovicoBessi.: Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.1p2)

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (**including the
>   underscore _,** the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other
>   characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as
>   described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct.
>   There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.

So yes it's a valid identifier name. And it's the 4d array.

So what else is done over here - let's go step by step. if `_` is the array then those inside `[]` are the indices of it.

So what is `!` ? From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p5)

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is `0` if the value of its operand compares unequal to `0`, `1` if the value of its operand compares equal to `0`. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

So it results in that the value of the indices would `0,1`. Well that's right all the array in this multidimensional array are of size `2`. So it's ok - we can access all the elements wit `0` and `1`.

`x` is a char - `sizeof char` is `1`- 1 Byte.

```
x [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

Now you do this `x&0x80` which is nothing but `And` ing the result with `0x80 - 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`.

So basically checking the respective digits and OR ing it with the value of `char` variable.

Why value of `char` variable - isn't it `x&15`?

`15` (`0x0F`)is `0000 1111` anding them with any value of `x` will result in last 4 bits (LSB) `x`.